# Why this neo4j cypher query fails to rewrite?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to submit this query to my neo4j-community database:

```
MATCH (n1:Hashtag{name:'animal'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n1,{}) YIELD node
WHERE node.postsCount > 1000 AND node.postsCount < 200000
RETURN node LIMIT 50
```

Neo4j Browser returns this error message:

**ERROR Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError**

```
    Failed rewriting AndedPropertyInequalities(Variable(node),CachedProperty(node,Variable(node),PropertyKeyName(postsCount),NODE_TYPE),LessThan(CachedProperty(node,Variable(node),PropertyKeyName(postsCount),NODE_TYPE),ParameterFromSlot(0,  AUTOINT2,Integer)), GreaterThan(CachedProperty(node,Variable(node),PropertyKeyName(postsCount),NODE_TYPE),ParameterFromSlot(1,  AUTOINT1,Integer)))
Tried using children: ReferenceFromSlot(0,node),NullCheckReference(0,SlottedCachedPropertyWithPropertyToken(node,PropertyKeyName(postsCount),0,false,1,1,NODE_TYPE,true)),LessThan(NullCheckReference(0,SlottedCachedPropertyWithPropertyToken(node,PropertyKeyName(postsCount),0,false,1,1,NODE_TYPE,true)),ParameterFromSlot(0,  AUTOINT2,Integer)), GreaterThan(NullCheckReference(0,SlottedCachedPropertyWithPropertyToken(node,PropertyKeyName(postsCount),0,false,1,1,NODE_TYPE,true)),ParameterFromSlot(1,  AUTOINT1,Integer))
```

I've tryied another similar query:

```
MATCH (n1:Hashtag{name:'animal'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n1,{}) YIELD node
WHERE node.postsCount > 1000
WITH node
WHERE node.postsCount < 200000
RETURN node LIMIT 50
```

With the same result. 
Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a possible APOC bug. You may want to submit an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by updating APOC to 4.0.0.8 and by installing Neo4j via the apt repository.